# How to force magento to logout

Tags: magento

I am working in magento community-1.6. I need to clear session or logout the current user at one stage of my site process. How will I do this.?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `logoutAction` of `AcountController`(app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php) or directly the `logout()` method of `Session`(app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php) if you have customer's session object.

Comment: Is there any way to find logout admin users using an event for a admin user logout?