# Magento - Force admin user log out

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am writing a module for Magento that only allows users to login from specific IP addresses.

I am hooking into

```
 admin_session_user_login_success
```

and when my function runs, I am attempting to run

```
 Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->logout();
```

however that function does not exist

```
 Invalid method Mage_Admin_Model_Session::logout
```

I read on

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455022/how-to-force-magento-to-logout
```

that the account controller or the session controller can also be used to log the user out but I am not sure how to logout an admin user.

Any snippets or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to logout admin users with the following snippet

```
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminSession->unsetAll();
$adminSession->getCookie()->delete($adminSession->getSessionName());
```

Comment: I have a query on this, how to find out a admin user is logged out using an event observer?