# How to force customer to log out in Magento

Tags: php, session, magento, magento-1.9

Is there any ways to force a customer to log out? The use case is that after changing the customer's group in backend, i would need to force him to log out and log back in to see the new prices for his new group. I'm not trying to log the current user out so can't use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout()`

I looked into sessions but there seems to be no way to init a session from a customer's ID

What i tried was setting customer id directly but it doesn't work

```
$session = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->loginById(1234)->logout();
```

Comment: Dis you try this Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout(); ?

Comment: @SiderTopalov i'm trying to programmatically force another user on the frontend to log out, not the current backend user

Comment: Check [that](http://webextent.blogspot.bg/2016/04/customer-logout-in-magento.html?m=1) i think this is what you want?

Comment: Could you perhaps redirect the user to a home page after changing their group (presumably when they attempt to access a page belonging to a specific you're checking that they actually have permission to access that page)

Comment: @SpacePhoenix it's not about page permission, it's because that i have different prices for different groups and that only gets refreshed once user logs out and logs back in

Comment: Hi @LongMKNguyễn, did you manage to get this solved? I also need to force logout of a customer (but not the current backend user)

Comment: @PauGNU i still haven't figured out a way get the correct session of a customer using their customer id, but i just upgraded to using Magento 2 and this feature is out of the box.

Comment: @LongMKNguyễn Are you able to resolve this on Magento2 ? I am observing same problem. Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: The feature is out of the box in Magento 2 for me, i was able to use the feature after upgrading, didn't make any further modifications to it, i didn't jump into their code to see how they were doing it tho

Answer (score 0):

This is how you find and delete Magento 1 customer session files.

1. Find the customer's id via Magento Admin Panel, e.g. `.../customer/edit/id/666/` => 666
2. Connect to your server through SSH
3. Change your current directory to MAGENTO_ROOT
4. List session files under `Magento_Root/var/session/`
   (replace 666 with actual customer id)

   ```
   grep -lr "\"customer_id\";s:5:\"666\"" ./var/session/
   ```
5. Delete all listed files.

One-liner for steps 4. and 5., use with caution! (replace 666 with actual customer id):

```
grep -lr "\"customer_id\";s:5:\"666\"" ./var/session/ | xargs rm
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout()` or redirect the customer to the below url

```
/customer/account/logout/
```

[How to force magento to logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455022/how-to-force-magento-to-logout/8665887#8665887)